# How to validate hex input with std::cin?

Tags: c++, input

I did the following method as in http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html to validate, but it does not work:

```
if (!(cin >> hex >>address1))
    {
        cout << "Invalid input.";               
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
```

It keeps carrying the remaining input to the next input, thus making the next input cannot be typed in by user, even the std::cin is cleared and ignored.

Comment: What do you mean by the "remaining input"? it should take everything up until you hit enter or if there's a space in the string.

Comment: It means I have another cin right after the above input, and the previous input was applied to the current cin, and user does not have a chance to input something.

Comment: Did you try putting a statement like `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` in between, or just a `std::cin.ignore()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess I'd do something like this:

```
std::getline(cin, your_string);

if (your_string.find_first_not_of("0123456789abcdefABCDEF") != std::string::npos)
    error("Non-hexadecimal input");
else {
    std::istringstream is(your_string);
    is >> std::hex >> address1;
}
```

There are a lot of variations, but the three steps I'd follow would be:

1. read the whole line,
2. validate it
3. convert if good.

Comment: parameters of `getline` backwards?  Is there some advantage of `std::getline(cin, s)` over `cin.getline(s)`?

Comment: @Ben: Oops -- fixed. Thank you. The member-function version of `getline` only works with buffers of char, where the global works with `std::string`s. To use the former safely at all, you *must* pass the buffer size, which is less convenient.

Answer (score 1):

Grab the input using `getline()` and step through the string, making sure there are only digits and the letters A-F  (and perhaps a leading 0x)

Comment: Well I have to do it with sdt::cin. Is there a way to do?

Comment: Sure, you can do it with a string input by cin.